# React Native compiling for Android -Beginner

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am a newbie to react native.

1.) I need to know if I can create a react native application and import it to Xcode, then add code in swift?

2.) I also need to know if the components I developed with swift can be compiled and run as a Android application?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can definitely do this, it's pretty common.
2. No, that swift code will not run on android

To help understand this, all UI code written in React Native is translated into corresponding native languages, everything else stays as Javascript.

Your Swift code **cannot** be translated back into Javascript that can then run on Android and certainly cannot be translated into Java.